# Unable to scrape the src if it is nested inside the source tag inside video via python selenium and beautiful soup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I was scraping an anime website as a project but when I tried to scrape the src it gave me an error. The src is nested inside the source tag. I am giving the screenshot and code below.

[example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXcxb.png)

Code :

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#launch url
url = "https://bestdubbedanime.com/Demon-Slayer-Kimetsu-no-Yaiba/26"

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

# python_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('playostki') #FHSU
# python_button.click() #click fhsu link

  soup1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

  video = soup1.find('video', id='my_video_1_html5_api')
  # video = driver.find_element_by_id('my_video_1_html5_api')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".playostki"))).click()      
   driver.stop_client
   driver.close
   driver.quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting the src tag, because it is displayed after clicking the video. You have to first click on that video, and then try to find the attribute "src" from the element.

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://bestdubbedanime.com/Demon-Slayer-Kimetsu-no-Yaiba/26")
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,  "//div[@class='playostki']//img"))).click()
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#my_video_1_html5_api > source"))).get_attribute("src"))
driver.quit()
```

**Output:**

```
https://bestdubbedanime.com/xz/api/v.php?u=eVcxb0ZCUEMraFd1Vi9pM2xqWUhtbXZMWjZ0Mlpoc1U0Tmhqc2VFcVViQUc3VUVhR0pZV1EvaW1nY1duaXBMeXYvUUY4RG5ab3p4MEtEMUFHRmVaN0taVG9sY3ZVcTRoeDZoVHhWLzdiYjQ5UStNN2FYSjJBSWNKL0t5S1hLNGEyVlZqV1BYQ2MwaCsyNWcvak1Db01EMnNtWGwwTTBBVld4MkNER0V3eGNCRXJ0cEY4RHFPclhwbTJpWFBPSmJI
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But can you tell me why my code didn't work because I also clicked  on the button. But Thanks

Comment: Because your css locator is not correct. It is highlighting multiple elements on page.

Comment: Oh thanks. And can I lessen the time too.

Comment: lessen the time too mean?

Comment: You have coded it to wait 60 seconds. It take quite time to load can I lessen the Time?

Comment: yeah yeah, this is explicit wait. It means, maximum it will wait for 60 seconds. If the element will appear in 2 seconds, it wouldn't wait for 60 seconds. It will execute in 2 seconds. But maximum it will wait for 60 seconds.

Comment: @QualityMatters Also do remember to discourage `implicitly_wait()` while using `WebDriverWait()`